# How to check all the values of trained variables in my tensorflow neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I already have my saved checkpoints, and I can use them to make predictions. However, I just want to take a look into my trained variables and know what exact values they are.

I am now using print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint.

I am also using sys.stdout to store the output into a txt file.

My current code looks like this:

```
from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file
import sys

def peekckpt(filePath):
    print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(filePath,None,True)

sys.stdout = open("tmp.txt",'w')
peekckpt("/save/model.ckpt-10000")
```

However, it won't display all the details. In tmp.txt, some variables are represented in the form of ellipsis (maybe because there are too many of them), for example:

```
tensor_name:  fully_connected_1/weights
[[ 0.01625621 -0.01740162  0.04686484 ... -0.02088195 -0.02621443
   0.00247668]
 [-0.00319242 -0.04545522  0.01150012 ...  0.00360141 -0.00241386
  -0.04921322]
 [ 0.04347562  0.00918857  0.00323885 ...  0.01275046 -0.06735339
   0.02492226]
```

**So, is there any way I can get rid of this ellipsis issue and let print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file() print all the variables?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following before my original code:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
```

This will work. It took around 30s - 40s, and finally I got a 81MB txt file.